# Functor fmap, pattern match function values, haskell

Tags: function, haskell, pattern-matching, functor

I have the following type, and would like to make it a Functor:

```
newtype SubsM a = SubsM {runSubsM :: Context -> Either Error (a, Env)}
```

So far i got this

```
instance Functor SubsM where
    fmap f (SubsM a)  =  SubsM (\s->(Right((f a),(fst s))))
```

I get an error because a is not the expected type, my question is how do i pattern match a on the left-hand side?

Comment: Please provide the definitions of `Context` and `Env`, as well as the exact error message you are getting.

Comment: Do those definitions matter? `fmap` is not allowed to touch those at all, since they don't have an `a` in them.

Comment: You may enjoy `type SubsM = Compose ((->) Context) (Compose (Either Error) ((,) Env))`. It is isomorphic to your definition, already has the requisite `Functor` instance, and even gives you an `Applicative` instance for free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pattern match on the `Either Error (a, Env)` with `case`:

```
instance Functor SubsM where
  fmap f (SubsM cf) = SubsM $ \c ->  case (cf c) of
    Left err -> Left err
    Right (v, env) -> Right (f v, env)
```

In the `Left` case you propagate the error, in the `Right` case you unpack the resulting pair and apply `f` to the first element.

Comment: I'd handle the `Right` case first and then just use a wildcard `val -> val` for `Left`.

Comment: You can't, because that has the wrong type. `val :: Either Error (a, Env)`, but you need `Either Error (b, Env)`.

Answer (score 7):

I prefer not to have to think, when the machine is quite capable of doing the thinking for you.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}

newtype SubsM a = SubsM {runSubsM :: Context -> Either Error (a, Env)}
    deriving Functor
```

Answer (score 5):

Note that you can also use the existing `Functor` instances for `->` and `Either` to do much of the work for you:

```
instance Functor SubsM where
  fmap g (SubsM cf) = SubsM (fmap (fmap (leftfmap g)) cf)
    where
      leftfmap f (a, b) = (f a, b)
```

The `Functor` instance for `(,)` maps over the right-hand value, not the left-hand one, so you can't use `fmap` there. You can also write `leftfmap` as `first` if you import that function from `Control.Arrow`.

Answer (score 4):

Much of the work necessary is already done for you since both `Either a b` and `(,)` are instance of the `Bifunctor` class.

```
-- Using the tuple instance
first f (x, y) == (f x, y)

-- Using the Either instance
second g (Left err) = Left err   -- basically, id
first g (Right v) = Right (g v)
```

Using these functions, you can shorten this drastically (a step-by-step reduction starting with Lee's answer follows):

```
import Data.Bifunctor
instance Functor SubsM where
   fmap f = SubsM . second (first f) . runSubsM
```

Would anyone actually write code like this, let alone do so from scratch? Probably not. It's not immediately obvious how it works, but deriving it one
step at a time is pretty straightforward, and you might find one of the intermediate steps useful.

I'd probably write something like

```
instance Functor SubsM where
  fmap f (SubsM cf) = SubsM $ \c -> (second . first) f (cf c)
```

which limits the more esoteric parts to the single function `(second . first)`.

---

### Derivation of the short form

First, use the `Bifunctor` instance of `(,)` to avoid pattern-matching
on the tuple.

```
-- first f (v, env) == (f v, env)
instance Functor SubsM where
   fmap f (SubsM cf) = SubsM $ \c ->  case (cf c) of
      Left err -> Left err
      Right t -> Right (first f t)
```

Next, use the `Bifunctor` instance of `Either a b` to avoid pattern-matching on the return value of `cf c`:

```
-- second (first f) (Left err) == Left Err
-- second (first f) (Right t) == Right (first f) t
instance Functor SubsM where
   fmap f (SubsM cf) = SubsM $ \c ->  second (first f) (cf c)
```

You can also avoid pattern-matching on the `SubsM` value by unpacking
it on the right-hand side with `runSubsM`:

```
instance Functor SubsM where
   fmap f cf = SubsM $ \c ->  second (first f) ((runSubsM cf) c)
```

Finally, we just start applying function composition to eliminate explict
arguments where possible.

```
instance Functor SubsM where
   -- fmap f cf = SubsM $ \c ->  second (first f) ((runSubsM cf) c)
   -- fmap f cf = SubsM $ \c ->  second (first f) . (runSubsM cf) $ c
   -- fmap f cf = SubsM $ second (first f) . (runSubsM cf)
   -- One more function composition allows us to drop cf as an
   -- explicit argument
   fmap f = SubsM . second (first f) . runSubsM
```

Comment: The interested reader might want to compare my answer to Daniel Martin's answer; they are nearly identical.