# How to write fmap for a Functor that has a function in it's data type definition?

Tags: haskell

I have data defined as below:

```
data FGM a = Pure a | GMAction Integer Integer (PlayerMsg -> FGM a)
data PlayerMsg = Guess Integer | Surrender
    deriving (Eq, Show)
```

FGM represents a number guessing game where the 2 integers are the upper and lower bounds, a is the value to be returned in the end, and playermsg is the guess that the player makes.
I would like to make FGM a Functor, so I'm trying to define a fmap for it. Problem is I don't know how do deal with the `(PlayerMsg -> FGM a)` part of FGM.

From my understanding of the testcases given, for `fmap g` (someFGM), g should only be applied to `Pure`, if it's `GMAction`, fmap should use `PlayerMsg` and generate the next FGM until it reaches a `Pure`.

This is what I've tried:

```
instance Functor FGM where
    fmap g (Pure a) = Pure (g a)
    fmap g (GMAction upper lower thing) = GMAction upper lower (fmap g (\x -> case (thing x) of 
                                                                                Pure a -> Pure a
                                                                                GMAction u l t -> GMAction u l t))
```

But when I try to run test on this I get this error:

```
Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type:
  b ~ FGM b
Expected type: PlayerMsg -> FGM b
  Actual type: PlayerMsg -> b
In the third argument of 'GMAction', namely '(fmap g (\x -> case (thing x) of 
                                                                                Pure a -> Pure a
                                                                                GMAction u l t -> GMAction u l t))'
In the expression:...
```

I've also tried

```
fmap g (GMAction upper lower thing) = GMAction upper lower (fmap g thing)
```

and got the same error.

I tried to search for examples with data that has a function as parameter like `PlayerMsg -> FGM a`, but can't find anything. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39515022/functor-fmap-pattern-match-function-values-haskell) is kind of similar but didn't work for me(it's my first failed example). Can someone help me define this fmap or point me at where to learn about this?

Comment: Side note: the lambda with the case expression amounts to `thing`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `fmap g (GMAction upper lower thing) = GMAction upper lower ((fmap g) . thing)`. Note the function composition; this is necessary as you need to `fmap` over the *result* of the function.

Comment: Yay it worked! Thank you!
yes that's typo I will edit it

Answer (score 4):

GHC's built-in rules for deriving `Functor` are enough to handle simple cases like this.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}
data FGM a = Pure a | GMAction Integer Integer (PlayerMsg -> FGM a) deriving Functor
data PlayerMsg = Guess Integer | Surrender
    deriving (Eq, Show)
```

Comment: Really - despite my answer above - this is what I usually use as well. It's nice having the computer write code for you!

Comment: @CeilviaC: You can also see the code that GHC generates from `deriving` clauses with the `-ddump-deriv` flag. (If you’re using Stack, this will generate a `.dump-deriv` file in your `.stack-work` directory.)